# Js Dates and switch function

Tags: javascript, html

the html file contains only a wrapper with the id "container" and of course the google apis for jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
for (i=1; i<=24; i++) {
    $("#container").append("<div class='divs' id='divs"    +i+     "'>"    +i+     "</div>");
} 
});
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
if(month == 11){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.divs').each(function () {
            $(this).click(function(){

                if($(this.id == day)){
                    alert("something");
                }else{
                    alert("something else");
                }
            });
    });
 });
 }
```

this is my code now. Is there any way for me to actually check if the id that contains a number (they all do) is the same as the date is.

Comment: Why would you use the switch **statement**? Are you making some kind of advent calendar?

Comment: Just a pointer, `$(document).ready()` is an event that fires on load of document. You do not need it inside `if`. Its is used to start the flow. Wrap your code in functions and call them inside `.ready` not define them

Comment: haha yeah advent calendar it is, some random school project

Comment: i also ran this "alert( $(".divs:checked").attr('class') );" but it said undefined on everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a switch statement with 24 different cases is one if the worst things you can do after doing the same with if...elses.

Instead you should give each div an id which tells you at which day they should be opened (at the end you'd have 24 divs each with the ids "0", "1", "2", ...).

When someone clicks on a div, get the date, check if it's december, and if it is, then check if the div's id is the same as current day.

If you still want to go with a switch statement, they look like this:

```
switch (day) {
    case 0: 
        // Open the first div
        break;
    case 1: 
        // Open the second div
        break;
    // ...
}
```

I hope you see why this isn't the optimal solution

Answer (score -2):

This might work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth();
  var day = d.getDate();

  $('[class^="divs"]').click(function () {
    if(month == 11){  
        $(this).toggleClass('image'); 
    } else {
      alert("not allowed");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: "I'm trying to only allow user to open a specific div **within a specific day within december**" read the question